# Como definir as colunas no OneHotEncoder do Sklearn?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, sklearn

Estou tendo um pequeno problema em fazer um código de ML para classificação definir ao usar o OneHotEncoder para realizar a categorização. Estou acompanhando um curso que utilizou o recurso da seguinte maneira:

```
dados = pd.read_csv(...)

previsores = dados.iloc[:,0:14].values
classe = dados.iloc[:,14].values
```

Separei a matriz entre os parametros previsores e a classe. Dentre esse previsores possuo alguns parâmetros categóricos nominais (ou seja, não possuem nenhuma ordem hierárquica).

```
labelencoder_previsores = LabelEncoder()
lista = [1,3,5,6,7,8,9,13]

for x in lista:
    previsores[:, x] = labelencoder_previsores.fit_transform(previsores[:, x])
```

Aqui eu rotulei os mesmos, tirando do formato string para torná-los numéricos, porém, como não possuem ordem necessito usar o OneHotEncoder.

O problema é que no curso em questão o professor adiciona um parâmetro `categorical_features` para indicar quais colunas precisam desse tratamento específico, dessa forma:

```
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[1,3,5,6,7,8,9,13])
previsores = onehotencoder.fit_transform(previsores).toarray()
```

E aparentemente o esse atributo, categorical_features não existe mais, portanto estou procurando de que forma eu poderia resolver esse problema em fóruns, na documentação, mas esse é o terceiro algoritmo de ML que fiz na vida, então tá sendo bem difícil. Alguém sabe como eu poderia resolver isso?

Comment: André, boa  tarde! Você consegue disponibilizar os dados que você está utilizando? Já deu uma olhada no [ColumnTransformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html)?

Comment: Disponibilizo sim!
Aqui estão:
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/ (adult.data)

Eu estou olhando exatamente o Column Transformer no momento, mas até agora ainda estou apanhando, substitui aquela parte final do código por:

onehotencoder = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('1', OneHotEncoder(),[1,3,5,6,7,8,9,13])])
onehotencoder.fit_transform(previsores)

Estou tentando entender como usa.
Você poderia me dar uma ajuda com isso?
Desde já, obrigado!

Comment: Veja este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43588679/issue-with-onehotencoder-for-categorical-features), especificamente o EDIT da resposta mais votada.

Comment: Opa

ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('oh_enc', OneHotEncoder(sparse=False),[1,3,5,6,7,8,9,13])],remainder='passthrough')
ct.fit_transform(previsores)

Alterei aqui e não deu erro, dei um print antes e depois de usar esse column transformer e os valores estão iguais (conforme tinha que ser mesmo), como será que eu posso testar pra ver se tá tudo ok?

Muito obrigado meu amigo!

Comment: `OneHotEncoder(sparse=False).fit_transform(dados.iloc[:,[1,3,5,6,7,8,9,13]])` Fazendo diretamente não resolveria seu problema?